# PHP Override way

Tags: php, oop

What is the PHP way to do a correct override ?

```
php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > error_reporting(E_ALL);
php > class A { public function z($a, $b){} }
php > class B extends A { public function z($a){parent::z($a, '1');} }
PHP Strict standards:  Declaration of B::z() should be compatible with A::z($a, $b) in php shell code on line 1
```

*Note: Override is the correct word in english ?*

Comment: Yes, override is right in this case. _Work_ is not, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the E_STRICT notice (which is just a programming hint, not an error as such) is that a child class should theoretically be usable interchangeably with its parent (the posh term is the "Liskov Substitution Principle").

In your case, you need to *know* that you have an instance of `B` in order to leave off the second parameter. PHP is being relaxed and letting you do it, but it's not really how inheritance should work - `B extends A` should mean that everything that "is a `B`" also "is an `A`".

If you used an `interface` to define the contract for `function z($a, $b)`, class `B` would violate that contract.

A better approach for this problem would be to use *delegation* rather than *inheritance*: class `B` could act as an "adaptor" which uses `A`'s behaviour, but simplifies it, e.g.

```
class B
{
    private $delegated_a;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->delegated_a = new A;
    }

    public function z($a) { 
        $this->delegated_a->z($a, '1');
    }
}
```

Here, we're making no promise to calling code about the relationship between `A` and `B`, so can re-define the methods however we like.

Comment: s/`A inherits B`/`B extends A`/

Comment: Needs the `A` and `B` swapped as well, as `B` is representing the subclass elsewhere. Otherwise your statement is equivalent to, "`Dog extends Mammal` should mean that everything that 'is a `Mammal`' also 'is a `Dog`'."

Comment: @cHao D'oh! Fixed as well!

Answer (score 2):

In your example, in `class A` function `z` have 2 parameters, in `class B` you are trying to declare it with 1 parameter. In php it wont work.

Btw. I guess you probably want to OVERLOAD funciotn `z` not override it, and it is not really supported in php. If I'm right here is little explanation fro manual:

Note:

PHP's interpretation of "overloading" is different than most object oriented languages. Overloading traditionally provides the ability to have multiple methods with the same name but different quantities and types of arguments.

Comment: It works just fine in my experience, except for triggering E_STRICT notices and flouting LSP.  (The two are almost certainly related.)

Comment: Isn't _overload_ from languages where same operator can take different number/types of parameters (and therefore have different behavior)? What child class does in php is exactly _overrides_ it's parent's method/properties.

Comment: @Cthulhu In the example, it's actually doing both: it's *overriding* the parent method, but varying the number of parameters, which in some languages would mean it instead *overloads* that method...

Comment: @IMSoP It is entirely different for the topic starter obviously wanted derived class's method not only have different parameters but replace the parent's one with itself, so what he was actually doing was overriding. When overloading, both methods are supposed to exist together.

Comment: Yes, i want override and not overload :)

Comment: Sorry then for misleading answer, thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You mean method overloading :)

Well actually this works a bit different then you would expect if you programmed in Java before. Please also checkout the comment in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).

The difference is that in eg. Java you can have multiple methods with the same name but another footprint. Eg:

```
public void max(int a, int b) {
    // calculate max value
}

public void max(double a, double b, double c) {
    // do some other calculation
}
```

Now if you would call the method max, Java will automatically decide which method to use.

Now in PHP this does not work. You can overwrite a method in a child class, but only if the footprint is the same, and you can only define the method in the child class. Example:

```
class A {
    function z($a, $b) {
        echo 'called in A';
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function z($a, $b) {
        echo 'called in B';
    }
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;

$a->z(1, 2); // prints out "called in A"
$b->z(1, 2); // prints out "called in B"
```

Comment: If you'd take a look at that page you linked, you'd see that in PHP, "overloading" very specifically refers to the use of magic methods.

Comment: I think you mean "fingerprint", or more commonly "signature", rather than "footprint".

Comment: @cHao, that's why I stated it's a bit different, with a bit of sense of understatement ;)
IMSoP: yup, you're right!